# Term set not showing in SQL Server

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, sql-server, term-set

I administrate a SharePoint 2013 site on which a bunch of managed metadata term sets are used (picture):

[image]

The last term set "Subject Area" is not looking like the rest of them, and has no associated data in our SQL Server database. Anyone who has any knowledge about its different appearance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Term Set which is not available for `Tagging` is seen with such an `icon` which differs from other in the list.

I suspect your term set `Subject Area` is set to not available for tagging.

To confirm refer below screen shots.

Check a term set which is available for tagging: If you notice in the tab `Intended Use` this `Temp` term set is enabled for `Available for tagging` properety, hence the icon resembles with others.

[image]

After disabling property: Once the `Available for tagging` property is disabled then the icon image is changed to a different one which has a different representation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Just the information I was looking for. 
For some reason it's not possible to extract terms in MS SQL Server from SharePoint, which are not "available for tagging".